# backup:run command throws generic error: ''mysqldump" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backup

I would like to inform you that I have already looked at this problem. Most of the Answers suggested that I should correct the absolute path in config/database.php and I did, yet the problem remained. I am pasting portions of my config and backup file That I created from Laravel Spatie DB Backup here. Thanks.

Config/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'dump' => [
                'use_single_transaction',
                'dump_command_path' =>'E:\xampp\mysql\bin',//That's the location of mysqldump in my PC
                'timeout' => 5,
                'dump_command_timeout' => 60,
            ],
        ],
```

and My backup file:

```
<?php

return [

    'backup' => [

        /*
         * The name of this application. You can use this name to monitor
         * the backups.
         */
        'name' => config('app.name'),

        'source' => [

            'files' => [

                /*
                 * The list of directories and files that will be included in the backup.
                 */
                'include' => [
                    base_path(),
                ],

                /*
                 * These directories and files will be excluded from the backup.
                 *
                 * Directories used by the backup process will automatically be excluded.
                 */
                'exclude' => [
                    base_path('vendor'),
                    base_path('node_modules'),
                ],

                /*
                 * Determines if symlinks should be followed.
                 */
                'followLinks' => false,
            ],

            /*
             * The names of the connections to the databases that should be backed up
             * MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and Mongo databases are supported.
             *
             * The content of the database dump may be customized for each connection
             * by adding a 'dump' key to the connection settings in config/database.php.
             * E.g.
             * 'mysql' => [
             *       ...
             *      'dump' => [
             *           'excludeTables' => [
             *                'table_to_exclude_from_backup',
             *                'another_table_to_exclude'
             *            ]
             *       ]
             * ],
             *
             * For a complete list of available customization options, see https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper
             */
            'databases' => [
                'mysql',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The database dump can be compressed to decrease diskspace usage.
         *
         * Out of the box Laravel-backup supplies
         * Spatie\DbDumper\Compressors\GzipCompressor::class.
         *
         * You can also create custom compressor. More info on that here:
         * https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper#using-compression
         *
         * If you do not want any compressor at all, set it to null.
         */
        'database_dump_compressor' => null,

        'destination' => [

            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => '',

            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'local',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The directory where the temporary files will be stored.
         */
        'temporary_directory' => storage_path('app/backup-temp'),
    ],

    /*
     * You can get notified when specific events occur. Out of the box you can use 'mail' and 'slack'.
     * For Slack you need to install guzzlehttp/guzzle.
     *
     * You can also use your own notification classes, just make sure the class is named after one of
     * the `Spatie\Backup\Events` classes.
     */
    'notifications' => [

        'notifications' => [
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupHasFailed::class         => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\UnhealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupHasFailed::class        => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupWasSuccessful::class     => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\HealthyBackupWasFound::class   => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupWasSuccessful::class    => ['mail'],
        ],

        /*
         * Here you can specify the notifiable to which the notifications should be sent. The default
         * notifiable will use the variables specified in this config file.
         */
        'notifiable' => \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifiable::class,

        'mail' => [
            'to' => 'your@example.com',
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'webhook_url' => '',

            /*
             * If this is set to null the default channel of the webhook will be used.
             */
            'channel' => null,

            'username' => null,

            'icon' => null,

        ],
    ],

    /*
     * Here you can specify which backups should be monitored.
     * If a backup does not meet the specified requirements the
     * UnHealthyBackupWasFound event will be fired.
     */
    'monitorBackups' => [
        [
            'name' => config('app.name'),
            'disks' => ['local'],
            'newestBackupsShouldNotBeOlderThanDays' => 1,
            'storageUsedMayNotBeHigherThanMegabytes' => 5000,
        ],

        /*
        [
            'name' => 'name of the second app',
            'disks' => ['local', 's3'],
            'newestBackupsShouldNotBeOlderThanDays' => 1,
            'storageUsedMayNotBeHigherThanMegabytes' => 5000,
        ],
        */
    ],

    'cleanup' => [
        /*
         * The strategy that will be used to cleanup old backups. The default strategy
         * will keep all backups for a certain amount of days. After that period only
         * a daily backup will be kept. After that period only weekly backups will
         * be kept and so on.
         *
         * No matter how you configure it the default strategy will never
         * delete the newest backup.
         */
        'strategy' => \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Cleanup\Strategies\DefaultStrategy::class,

        'defaultStrategy' => [

            /*
             * The number of days for which backups must be kept.
             */
            'keepAllBackupsForDays' => 7,

            /*
             * The number of days for which daily backups must be kept.
             */
            'keepDailyBackupsForDays' => 16,

            /*
             * The number of weeks for which one weekly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keepWeeklyBackupsForWeeks' => 8,

            /*
             * The number of months for which one monthly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keepMonthlyBackupsForMonths' => 4,

            /*
             * The number of years for which one yearly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keepYearlyBackupsForYears' => 2,

            /*
             * After cleaning up the backups remove the oldest backup until
             * this amount of megabytes has been reached.
             */
            'deleteOldestBackupsWhenUsingMoreMegabytesThan' => 5000,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

add the entry below on your config/database.php under `'driver' => 'mysql'`

`'dump' => [ 'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin'],`